# What happens to column contents when I change the Identity property of DB2 v11 databases?

Tags: db2, identity-column

Will the values of identity columns of already filled tables remain when I change the properties of the identity columns?

I have two tables with one INTEGER identity column. In one table `table1` I just want to disable this property. In the other table `table2` I want to change the value range of the identity counter.

The idea to do this is as follows:

```
db2 "alter table <table1> ALTER COLUMN <column> drop IDENTITY"

db2 "alter table <table2> ALTER COLUMN <column> drop IDENTITY" 
db2 "alter table <table2> ALTER COLUMN <column> set generated always as identity  
     (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, MINVALUE 1, MAXVALUE 65536, CYCLE, NO CACHE, NO ORDER)".
```

Since I only change the properties of the column in table 1 and increase the value range of the column in table 2, I expect the values in the affected columns to be preserved. Or are all values always set to NULL with a drop IDENTITY?

Comment: Db2 for z/OS v11? Db2 for LUW 11.1? 11.5? Did you have a chance to look at the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to test by yourself, isn't it?

```
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "create table test(f1 int not null generated always as identity, f2 varchar(20))"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "insert into test (f2) values ('foobar')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "insert into test (f2) values ('foobar')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "select * from test"

F1          F2
----------- --------------------
          1 foobar
          2 foobar

  2 record(s) selected.

[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "alter table test alter column f1 drop identity"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "select * from test"

F1          F2
----------- --------------------
          1 foobar
          2 foobar

  2 record(s) selected.
```

So no, existing values of the former `IDENTITY` won't be modified.

Note however that if you re-create the identity on `table2` the way you show, it will generate at least some values that overlap with existing values, leading to duplicate "identities" or insert exceptions.

```
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "alter table test alter column f1 set generated always as identity
>      (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, MINVALUE 1)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "insert into test (f2) values ('foobar')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@somehost ~]$ db2 "select * from test"

F1          F2
----------- --------------------
          1 foobar
          2 foobar
          1 foobar

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Super - two very good hints - thank you very much.

1) The values obviously remain the same.

2) If you start at 1 again, there are exceptions logically, so I have to get the highest value +1 with a subquery first.

Many thanks again!